# Special characters are input wrongly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm having a queer issue. I have this code in Java:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter word: ");
String word = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println(word);
```

However, for special characters, the scanner class seems to be going wrong. For example, if I type in `ħabel` I get `Ä§abel` printed. Eclipse's  console output is set as UTF-8, sure of that, so I think it's coming from the input. I haven't found any encoding options in the Scanner class really and funnily googling about didn't give solutions neither. How could this be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the special character you used?

Answer (score 2):

When you set up a `Scanner` on a bare `InputStream`, it reads using the default charset (which for you seems to be ASCII). If you want to specify the charset, do this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669056/unicode-input-in-a-console-application-in-java

Comment: As pointed out in the question above, console input in Windows doesn't seem to work on special characters. I reverted to reading the input from a file. Thanks Russel

Answer (score 1):

I believe Russel answer is correct, but it seems that your **input** charset is not `UTF-8`
Try this: 
`Scanner s= new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in,Charset.defaultCharset()));`

Comment: this answer is the best solution