# New glyphs in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

Is there a way to read the new unicode characters or glyphs I guess, like the Ever Green Green (U+1F332), the mountain (U+26F0), and the Man in a suit (U+1F574) in java? I really want to implement this into a game I'm writing but I don't know how. Apache's extension library is not acceptable, sorry.

Comment: What have you tried?  How has it failed?  As far as I know, Java itself has no special restriction to characters defined in any particular version of Unicode.

Comment: Do note, however, that *reading* characters is worlds different from printing / displaying graphic representations of them.  The latter requires use of a font that has glyphs for the characters in question; that might be hard to come by for characters that have only recently been added.

Comment: Usually [the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html) are a great place to start when you have "How is this common action done in Java?" questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I implied in comments, your problem is unlikely to be with *reading* the characters.  Java should be able to read them (and write them) just fine.  For example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class NewChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // UTF-16 (surrogate pairs) for the two characters mentioned:
        String theChars = "\ud87c\udf32\ud87e\udd74";

        // Write the characters to a (UTF-8 encoded) byte stream:
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "UTF-8");

        out.write(theChars);
        out.close();

        // Read the characters back
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), "UTF-8"));
        String readBack = in.readLine();

        // Check the result (prints "Readback is good"):
        System.out.println(theChars.equals(readBack) ? "Readback is good"
                : "Readback is bad");
    }
}
```

The problem is very likely that your system does not have a font that contains glyphs for those characters.  The glyph you describe seeing -- a square or diamond with a question mark inside -- is one of the commonly-used substitution glyphs emitted in a place of a character for which the chosen font has no other glyph.

This is not a Java problem.  You need updated fonts, probably from your OS vendor, and they may or may not be available.  Moreover, it would be wise to avoid depending on characters that *others* might not have supporting fonts for, either, unless you only intend for your program to work as intended on the computer on which you develop it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes more sense and I can't require my professor to upgrade his system. LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    System.out.println(new String(Character.toChars(0x1f332)));
    System.out.println(new String(Character.toChars(0x26f0)));
    System.out.println(new String(Character.toChars(0x1f574)));
```

First and third characters are surrogate pairs.

Comment: There is no character in the font you are using.

Comment: That maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20386335/2654103) is relevant. (If you are using a console in windows)

Comment: This works fine for me but my professor is a mac user so it doesn't work for hiim.