# Java print string as unicode

Tags: java, unicode, encoding

I was processing some data tweeter using java. I read them from the file, do some process and print to the `stdout`.
The text in file looks like this:

> "RT @Bollogosta319a: #BuyBookSilentSinners \u262fGain Followers\n\u262fRT  This\n\u262fMUST FOLLOW ME I FOLLOW BACK\n\u262fFollow everyone who  rts\n\u262fGain\n  #ANDROID \u2026"

I read it in, and print it out to stdout. The output is supposed to be:

> "RT @Bollogosta319a: #BuyBookSilentSinners ☯Gain Followers\n☯RT This\n☯MUST FOLLOW ME I FOLLOW BACK\n☯Follow everyone who rts\n☯Gain\n  #ANDROID …"

But my output is like this:

> "RT @Bollogosta319a: #BuyBookSilentSinners ?Gain Followers
>   ?RT This
>   ?MUST FOLLOW ME I FOLLOW BACK
>   ?Follow everyone who rts
>   ?Gain
>     #ANDROID ?"

So, it seems that I have two problems to deal with:
 1. print the exact `Unicode character` instead of `Unicode string`
 2. keep `"\n"` as it is, instead of a newline in the output.

How can I do this? (I'm really crazy about dealing with different coding in Java)

Comment: what you tried ? can you post ?

Comment: If you want to have unicode (such as ☯) in your out stream you need to ensure the stream is using UTF8. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386335/printing-out-unicode-from-java-code-issue-in-windows-console for how to do this.

Comment: Actually, I want to know more about the encoding process behind read and write. As it read text from file, I even don't know how it's represented. If I try to print it out, it will show up as some another encoding representation....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are parsing the file, but the method you are using seems to be interpreting escape codes (like `\n` and `\u262f`). To leave instances of `\n` in the file literally, you could replace `\n` with `\\n` prior to using whatever means of interpreting the escape codes. The `\\` will be converted to a single `\`, and the `n` will be left alone. Have you tried using a plain `java.io.FileReader` to read the file? That may be simpler.

The Unicode symbols may actually be read correctly; many terminals do not support the full range of Unicode characters and print some symbol in place of those it does not understand. Perhaps your program prints `☯` and the terminal simply doesn't know how to render it, so it prints a `?` instead.