# How to print Unicode symbols U+2610 and U+2612 to Windows console with Java?

Tags: java, windows, unicode, console, cyrillic

What I do:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char i = 0x25A0;
        System.out.println(i);
        i = 0x2612;
        System.out.println(i);
        i = 0x2610;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

What I get in IDE:

[image: What I get in IDE]

What I get in Windows console:

[image: What I get in Windows console]

I have Windows 10 (Russian locale), Cp866 default coding in console, UTF-8 coding in IDE.
How to make characters in console look correct?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/4828463

Comment: and look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14109024/4828463

Comment: Switching  `chcp 65001` and font change do not help

Comment: Oh then I am sorry. I tried looking it up for you

Comment: Do you know that you can write `System.out.println("\u25A0");`, instead of going through the `Character.toString` dance? (You can also write `System.out.println(i)`; or `char i = 0x25A0;`).

Comment: Tried all the options you offered. Same result as before. Thank you for options of printing characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems here, actually:

1. Java converts output to its default encoding which doesn't have anything to do with the console encoding, usually. This can apparently only be overridden at VM startup with, e.g.

   ```
   java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 MyClass
   ```
2. The console window has to use a TrueType font in order to display Unicode. However, neither Consolas, nor Lucida Console have ☐, or ☒. So they show up as boxes with Lucida Console and boxes with a question mark with Consolas (i.e. the *missing glyph* glyph). The output is still fine, you can copy/paste it easily, it just doesn't look right, and since the Windows console doesn't use font substitution (hard to do that with a character grid anyway), there's little you can do to make them show up.

I'd probably just use `[█]`, `[ ]`, and `[X]` instead.

Comment: I tried -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 and -Dfile.encoding=Cp866 before, none hepled. Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Well, Cp866 would not do any good, since the characters are not in that codepage

Comment: Ok, the main problem seems to be in absence of characters in fonts. There is still a quiestion why its ok in IDE. I have an idea that it is because Windows uses different encodings for graphical and console outputs, but Im not sure

Comment: Your IDE probably doesn't treat console output as a grid of character cells, but rather a text stream (as is usual in Unix, but not Windows) and displays it accordingly. Thus it probably can simply use normal text output and thus font substitution.

Answer (score 1):

> Cp866 default coding in console

well yeah. Code page 866 doesn't include characters U+25A0, U+2610 or U+2612. So even if Java were using the correct encoding for the console (either because you set something like `-Dfile.encoding=cp866`, or it guessed the right encoding, which it almost never manages), you couldn't get the characters out.

> How to make characters in console look correct?

You can't.

In theory you could use `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`, and set the console encoding to UTF-8 (or near enough, code page 65001). Unfortunately the Windows console is broken for multi-byte encodings (other than the legacy locale-default supported ones, which UTF-8 isn't); you'll get garbled output and hangs on input. This approach is normally unworkable.

The only reliable way to get Unicode to the Windows console is to skip the byte-based C-standard-library I/O functions that Java uses and go straight to the Win32 native WriteConsoleW interface, which accepts Unicode characters (well, UTF-16 code units, same as Java strings) and so avoids the console bugs in byte conversion. You can use JNA to access this API—see example code in this question: [Java, UTF-8, and Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952/java-utf-8-and-windows-console) though it takes some extra tedious work if you want to make it switch between console character output and regular byte output for command piping.

And *then* you have to hope the user has non-raster fonts (as @Joey mentioned), then *then* you have to hope the font has glyphs for the characters you want (Consolas doesn't for U+2610 or U+22612). Unless you really really have to, getting the Windows console to do Unicode is largely a waste of your time.

Comment: Good point, I actually forgot that Java uses the non-wide C API underneath which is in itself a fun source of problems ;-)

Comment: @Joey: yes, and it's worse than that: even using the wide C stdlib API is broken by default. You can sort-of fix it up with `_setmode(stream, _O_U8TEXT)`, but then you can't ever use the narrow stream APIs as they crash. I imagine Java would probably not be happy. :-) this is all such a horrendous disaster

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the font you use, has characters to display the Unicode? No font supports every possible Unicode character. U+9744,9632 and 9746 are not supported by e.g. the Arial font. You can Change the font of your IDE console and your Windows console too.

Comment: I am not completely sure that font has characters, but I used same fonts "Consolas" and "Lucida Console" in IDE and console, and every time it was correct in IDE and incorrect in console. So I suppose the problem is encoding.

Comment: Please correct your code example. You are using different Unicodes, than in the Pictures you appended.

Back to the Topic:
Do you try to change the codepage of your console?
Use the command **chcp 65001** to Change your codepage to 65001. Then try to type ALT + 02610 (on numpad). Is the Icon visible?

Comment: Updated code example, same resulta in IDE and console. Tried chcp 65001 and ALT + 02610, no icon shown in console, just number "2".

Comment: Since they get question marks this is (at first at least) *not* a font problem but rather an encoding conversion mangling the output.

Comment: I did a bit of research. It seems like Java is resetting the console Codepage. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669056/unicode-input-in-a-console-application-in-java