# Java changing unicode character Θ to?

Tags: unicode

I'm trying to use Unicode character `Θ` (\u0398) in my java program, But when I print that character, I'm getting `?`.

`System.getProperty("file.encoding")` is showing value `Cp1252` on my machine. I have tried to change this property to `UTF8`, But I'm still getting ?.
The sample code that I use in my test program is given below.

```
 char[] CHAR_TABLE = { '@', '\u0398', '1', };
 for(int i=0; i< CHAR_TABLE.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(CHAR_TABLE[i]);
 }
```

The output of this code is:

```
@
?
1
```

I was facing the same issue in another Java application (on another machine), but after service restart everything was fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print Unicode symbols U+2610 and U+2612 to Windows console with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480295/how-to-print-unicode-symbols-u2610-and-u2612-to-windows-console-with-java)

Comment: I have already tried this one and changed file.encoding at startup. But still no luck